# How can I type accents in Lubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu

I have a US keyboard, and mostly type in English. However I also want to use it occasionally for typing Portuguese; I don't want to use the GUI character map.

How can I set up the keyboard and what packages should I install so that key combinations like  á = RightAlt + a will work?

I believe there is also a way to use tilde, apostrophe, and the quote key followed by a letter to achieve it, but of course it does not work by default, otherwise typing apostrophe would be difficult. However there must be a way to temporarily change something to use the keys that way.

I will mainly type in emacs, so if there is an emacs specific solution, that will also work.

Comment: I tried lxkeymap from the main menu, and set US International (with dead keys), and it gives me some accents (e.g., typing tilde once followed by a gives me ã, typing tilde twice gives me tilde, etc). But there are some problems. In /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us there is a section us(international). I don't see how to type the characters listed in the third and the forth columns. I believe there is a compose-key and I have to type, e.g., compose-key + shift + AC11 to get double quote. But I don't know what the compose-key is.

Answer (score 1):

I used Lxkeymap, set it in United States (my Lubuntu is in spanish so it is Estados Unidos), then selected English International (with dead keys Alt Gr) and it works fine in vim, and as you said, á = <kbd>RightAlt</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>.

I hope it works for emacs

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the compose key by putting this in your `~/.Xkbmap` file:

```
us -option compose:ralt
```

Here, `ralt` means right alt.  For the full list of compose key combos, see `/usr/share/X11/locale/$LANG/Compose` .  For more details, see `man 7 xkeyboard-config`

Unfortunately, it doesn't stick (e.g. stops working if you suspend and resume), so you may have to set it manually from time to time:

```
setxkbmap `cat ~/.Xkbmap`
```